# sorting np array vs python list yields different results

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I wanted to do a little numpy practice, so I decided to [borrow some quicksort code](http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/#python) and change it to use numpy.

This is the original:

```
def quicksort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    pivot = arr[len(arr) // 2]

    left = [x for x in arr if x < pivot]
    middle = [x for x in arr if x == pivot]
    right = [x for x in arr if x > pivot]

    return quicksort(left) + middle + quicksort(right)

print (quicksort([1,2,32,121,4,5,51]))
```

And here I change it to use numpy arrays

```
def quicksort_np(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    pivot = arr[len(arr) // 2]

    left = arr[arr < pivot]
    middle = arr[arr == pivot]
    right = arr[arr > pivot]

    return quicksort_np(left) + middle + quicksort_np(right)

print (quicksort_np(np.array([1,2,32,121,4,5,51])))
```

Running the original version, I get the correct output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 32, 51, 121]
```

However, running the numpy version, I get an **empty list**:

```
[]
```

I can't understand what the problem is. I thought it had to do with the new lists not being copies, so I tried calling `.copy()` on each list inside `quicksort_np`, but I still got the same output.

Comment: Porting list code to `numpy` is not a good way to learn `numpy`.  Superficial similarities can lead to bugs like this, and also promote poor `numpy` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is in your line:

`return quicksort_np(left) + middle + quicksort_np(right)`

The '+' operator is a concatenation operator for python lists, but a sum operator for numpy arrays.

You can probably solve the problem by using [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate)

Comment: Thanks very much. I guess I have to be careful of what I assume is common across python and numpy

Answer (score 2):

The + operator works on python lists but not on numpy arrays.

Try [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack) instead:

```
def quicksort_np(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    pivot = arr[len(arr) // 2]

    left = arr[arr < pivot]
    middle = arr[arr == pivot]
    right = arr[arr > pivot]

    return np.hstack((quicksort_np(left), middle, quicksort_np(right)))
```